# Jquery append link ( link 'click' not working )

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to append url from the server and show the link to the user to click it but the 'click' doesn't work. Can you help me fix it?

Thank you!

```
$("#uurl").append("<p><a target='_blank' href="+data[1]+">"+data[1]+"</a></p>")
```

Comment: Show complete code, What is the value of `data[1]`

Comment: It is just the url text @Satpal Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka, Really? as OP is using anchor with `href`. where does event delegation comes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some quotes...

use:

```
$("#uurl").append("<p><a target='_blank' href='"+data[1]+"'>"+data[1]+"</a></p>")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create element's using jQuery. It will prevent you from quotes mess.

```
//Create anchor
var a = $('<a />', {
            "target" : "_blank",
            "href" : data[1],
            "text" : data[1]
        });

//Create paragraph and append anchor
var p = $('<p />').append(a);

//Append Paragraph
$("#uurl").append(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with

```
$("#uurl").append("<p><a target='_blank' href='"+data[1]+"'>"+data[1]+"</a></p>")
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#uurl").append("<p><a target='_blank' href='"+data[1]+"'>"+data[1]+"</a></p>")` Should work. You forgot quotes for the href attribute's value

Comment: which is still valid syntax in html5

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around href, try putting it using escape character

```
$("#uurl").append("<p><a target='_blank' href=\""+data[1]+"\">"+data[1]+"</a></p>")
```